# Trying to show player names in a column in discord.js embed bot

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, embed

Hey guys im trying to figure out how make an embed in a bot that basically shows a teams roster, but I can't figure out how to make the team players names in a column. I tried putting it in .addfield but it didn't work. Heres an example of what I'm trying to do [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGONH.png)

```
    case 'roster':
        const roster = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('FinalSpark')
        .setDescription('Rank: 3 | Region: EU | League: CCL')
        .setURL('https://club.mpcleague.com')
        .setFooter('bot made by alex :D')
        .addField('Roster')
        message.channel.send(roster);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that embed uses two fields, the second one having a blank title

The way you should go about this is first getting your roster list into an array, and then splitting the array in half:

```js
//your roster array
const roster = [];
//round up so the first row always either has equal or more items
//use Math.floor() if you want the opposite
const midIndex = Math.ceil(roster.length / 2);

const firstRow = roster.slice(0, midIndex);
const secondRow = roster.slice(midIndex);

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('FinalSpark')
    .setDescription('Rank: 3 | Region: EU | League: CCL')
    .setURL('https://club.mpcleague.com')
    .addField("Roster", firstRow.join("\n"), true);

if (secondRow.length) { 
    // \u200b is what makes the invisble effect, you can have \u200b
    // for both the key and value which would essentially make a blank line
    embed.addField("\u200b", secondRow.join("\n"), true);
}

message.channel.send(embed);
```

That would be inside of the case statement of course.